# Replace object element in array of objects if match found in java

Tags: java

In the code below the method will take array of 5 Library objects and one Library object as input. I would like  to replace the Library object if for the id of the object an object with same id is found in the array. The output will return true and print the 5 objects with the replaced object values. Else return false and print the array as it is.

For example:
If library object input is `18,rmgjynm,qxkhlbb`
Output will be

```
Output for performing replace is: false 
33 drfnfuk cqisthj 
78 xhzebcf nnpwbrf 
68 qnoquku qstcebj 
81 ghgwsjm xlewgbj 
47 wgioqsg vjtwscm
```

i.e no changes are made
If library object input is `47,tvistro,rnpholx`

```
Output for performing replace is: true
33 drfnfuk cqisthj 
78 xhzebcf nnpwbrf 
68 qnoquku qstcebj 
81 ghgwsjm xlewgbj 
47 tvistro rnpholx
```

The code I've written till now is as shown below. Please suggest changes as the code shows error of Cannot find symbol for inputlib elements.

```
public class LibraryDemo 
{
public static Library[] replaceLibraryById(Library[] objArray, Library inputlib)
{
    for(int i=0;i<objArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(inputlib.inputid==objArray[i].id)
        {
            objArray[i].setName=inputlib.inputname;
            objArray[i].setAddress=inputlib.inputadd;
            boolean tf=true;
            System.out.print("Output for performing replace on libraryRes1 is"+tf);
            for(Library:objArray)
            {
                System.out.println(library.getId()+" " + library.getName()+" " + library.getAddress()+" ");
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            boolean tf=false;
            System.out.print("Output for performing replace on libraryRes1 is"+tf);
            for(Library:objArray)
            {
                System.out.println(library.getId()+" " + library.getName()+" " + library.getAddress()+" ");
            }
        }
    }
    return replaceLibraryById();
}
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Library[] objArray=new Library[5];

    for(int i=0;i<objArray.length;i++)
    {
        int id=sc.nextInt();sc.nextLine();
        String name=sc.nextLine();
        String address=sc.nextLine();
        objArray[i]=new Library(id,name,address);
    }

    int inputid=sc.nextInt();sc.nextLine();
    String inputname=sc.nextLine();
    String inputadd=sc.nextLine();
    Library inputlib=new Library(inputid,inputname,inputadd);
    replaceLibraryById(objArray, inputlib);
}
}

class Library
{
int id;
String name;
String address;

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id=id;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}
public String getAddress()
{
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address)
{
    this.address=address;
}


public Library(int id,String name, String address)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.address=address;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres your corrected code have a look

```
public class findObject {


public static void replaceLibraryById(Library[] objArray, Library inputlib)
{
    boolean tf = false;
    for(int i=0;i<objArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(inputlib.id==objArray[i].id)
        {
            objArray[i].setName(inputlib.name);
            objArray[i].setAddress(inputlib.address);
            tf=true;
            System.out.println("Output for performing replace on libraryRes1 is : "+tf);
            for(Library l:objArray)
            {
                System.out.println(" " + l.getId()+" " + l.getName()+" " + l.getAddress()+" ");
            }
            break;
        }

    }


    if(tf != true) {
        System.out.println("Output for performing replace on libraryRes1 is : "+tf);
        for(Library l:objArray)
        {
            System.out.println(" " + l.getId()+" " + l.getName()+" " + l.getAddress()+" ");
        }
    }

    //return replaceLibraryById();
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Library[] objArray=new Library[5];

    System.out.println("Create the 5 class data below : ");

    for(int i=0;i<objArray.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("enter class id : ");
        int id=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("enter class name : ");
        String name=sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("enter class Address : ");
        String address=sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("id :" + id + " name : " + name + " Address :" + address);
        objArray[i]=new Library(id,name,address);
    }

    System.out.println("Search for a class : ");

    System.out.print("enter class id : ");
    int inputid=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("enter class name : ");
    String inputname=sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("enter class Address : ");
    String inputadd=sc.nextLine();

    Library inputlib=new Library(inputid,inputname,inputadd);
    replaceLibraryById(objArray, inputlib);
}
}
```

And the library class

```
class Library
{
int id;
String name;
String address;

public Library(int id,String name, String address)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.address=address;
}

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id=id;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}
public String getAddress()
{
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address)
{
    this.address=address;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain or give a link to a website which explains the syntax used in the for statement `for(Library l:objArray)` and how it works?

Comment: There is official docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html. Though to understand in more use case scenario, search articles by individuals like, https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/enhanced-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of syntax error. 
Your `replaceLibraryById()` method should look something like this:

```
public static Library[] replaceLibraryById(Library[] objArray, Library inputlib)
{
    for(int i=0;i<objArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(inputlib.getId()==objArray[i].getId())
        {
            objArray[i].setName(inputlib.getName());
            objArray[i].setAddress(inputlib.getAddress());
            boolean tf=true;
            System.out.print("Output for performing replace on libraryRes1 is"+tf);
            for(Library l :objArray)
            {
                System.out.println(l.getId()+" " + l.getName()+" " + l.getAddress()+" ");
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            boolean tf=false;
            System.out.print("Output for performing replace on libraryRes1 is"+tf);
            for(Library l :objArray)
            {
                System.out.println(l.getId()+" " + l.getName()+" " + l.getAddress()+" ");
            }
        }
    }
    return replaceLibraryById();
}
```

Also, what does the last line `return replaceLibraryById();` mean?
You either call it with appropriate arguments `(Library[] objArray, Library inputlib)` or remove from code.